# FileHelpers + async-await?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, filehelpers

I’m looking at using FileHelpers in a file reading/writing library. This library will be highly parallel and concurrent using async-await as well as Tasks.

As I understand it, FileHelperAsyncEngine is asynchronous internally, but there’s no *Async methods for async-await, so each file will tie up the calling thread until the file is loaded.

While it’s obviously possible to e.g. `Task.Run(…FileHelperAsyncEngine …)`, I will likely run into a thread creation performance bottleneck when trying to read thousands of small files (as parallel as possible) this way since the threadpool only spins up extra threads (i.e. more than #cores) once every 0.5 seconds, which has quite an overhead and is (in my context) too slow.

Ideally I would be able to e.g.

```
await ReadNextsAsync()
```

, or at least use the APM pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

- Are there any plans to add async-await support to FileHelpers?
- Do you see any good way to use the APM pattern with FileHelpers?

Thanks!
Kristian

Comment: A side-note - reading thousands of files in parallel is going to be limited by the drive throughput etc., so there really isn't any point (you're still wasting resources waiting for something you could have started a long time later). You'll probably want to use some form of throttling anyway, not reading more than e.g. 10 files at the same time (or better, limiting based on buffer sizes / file lengths - the OS and the HDD are pretty good at prioritizing disk access to optimize the total throughput). As always, you want to *test* the performance.

Comment: @Luaan: Good advice for the general case, but less applicable to my case and question:

Doing neither async-await nor Task.Run() would mean reading files one at a time, which is not an option.

I obviously don't want to read thousands of files in parallel, which is why I wrote "as parallel as possible".

The code needs to work well on SSD, HD and networks, and I strongly believe proper async code is the best way to do this, hence my question: "How to do async with FileHelpers" so that I can test my hypothesis.